# How to load an existing model (ontology) from a file?

Tags: java, jena, ontology

Let me start with what I have at the moment: I have a ready-made ontology in .rdf format, I work in Android Studio, I study Jena Fuseki in Studio. I have installed all the libraries I need.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPSO7.png)

My task is to load the already mentioned existing model (ontology) from a file. But the problem is that I get two kinds of exceptions: the first I encounter for the first time, and the second is illogical.

So, task is to load the already mentioned existing model (ontology) from a file. I do it this way:

```
Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
m.read("C://Users//xeniy//Desktop//DomenEng_04//L01_easy_for_L04.rdf");
m.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
```

I get an exception from the studio (first type), which can be seen in the screenshot:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/beldB.png)

I can not call myself a beginner in programming, but this is the first time I see such an exception. The method of googling gave the following variant: The problem is in the URL. On this basis, I changed the code:

```
Model m = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    try {
        m.read(new File("С:/Users/xeniy/Desktop/DomenEng_04/L01_easy_for_L04.rdf").toURL().toString());
        m.write(System.out, "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The exception, of course, had changed, only it left me even more stumped than the previous one (the second type of exception):
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQwsI.png)

It seems to be simple: DoesNotExistException directly says that the file you are looking for does not exist or is not found. But the file is definitely in the folder, and it can be opened, which means that it exists.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuhcx.png)

Comment: Did you try `file:///С:/Users/xeniy/Desktop/DomenEng_04/L01_easy_for_L04.rdf`?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Still DoesNotExistException.

Comment: This is androjena, not Apache Jena. Androjena is a very old fork.  It's for Android so maybe "C:" isn't correct. Try `file:///Users/xeniy/Desktop/DomenEng_04/L01_easy_for_L04.rdf`.

Comment: This URL also not working. I tried to write literally directly: (model.read("...."), and through new File and the toUrl() method.